# Converting to Swift substitute not working

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextview

Seems like these should substitute.  Not sure why they do not.

This works:

```
let postString = NSString(format:"Name=%@&Email=%@&Message=%@",nameTextField.text!,emailTextField.text!,messageTextView.text!)
```

Thinking this could substitute:

```
 let postString = "Name=\(nameTextField!)&Email=\(emailTextField!)&Message=\(messageTextView!)"
```

New to Swift, thank you.

Comment: You forgot `.text` in your substitute.

Comment: Of course. Worked great.  Still learning.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create the String with the constructor like this:

```
let postString = String(format:"Name=%@&Email=%@&Message=%@",nameTextField.text!,emailTextField.text!,messageTextView.text!)
```

For localized descriptions you can include the NSLocalizedString:

```
let postString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Name=%@&Email=%@&Message=%@", comment: "Some context for translator ease"),nameTextField.text!,emailTextField.text!,messageTextView.text!)
```

**EDIT:**

Adam's comment would most likely work and since you're going to use it for an http call it wouldn't make much sense to localize it, cheers anyway